# Group column in blocks of 4 observations and return 1 based on a condition

Tags: r, dataframe, grouping

Here my example data.frame:

```
    df = read.table(text = 'Value
    1
    1
    0
    1
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    1
    1
    1
    0
    1
    1
    0
    0
    0
    0', header = TRUE)
```

I need to divide the column in blocks of 4 and if there exists at least a 1 within each block I need to return a data.frame with 1s.

Here my expected result:

```
Result
1
1
1
```

Or also return a data.frame with 1s and 0s, where 0s are printed for blocks with no 1s:

```
Result
1
0
1
1
0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple vectorized way could be to convert to a 4 rows matrix and then run a `colSums` (this, ofcourse assumes your data length is dividable by 4)

```
as.integer(colSums(matrix(df$Value, 4)) > 0)
# [1] 1 0 1 1 0
```

Or using the matrixStats package

```
matrixStats::colMaxs(matrix(df$Value, 4))
# [1] 1 0 1 1 0
```

Answer (score 0):

With `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, grp := as.integer(gl(.N, 4, .N))][, +(any(Value==1)) , grp]$V1
#[1] 1 0 1 1 0
```

---

Or with `rowsum` from `base R`

```
+(rowsum(df$Value, gl(20, 4, 20))>0)
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(grp = gl(n(), 4, n())) %>%
    summarise(Value = max(Value))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R method that uses matrix multiplication to calculate the sum of 1 values and then uses `sign` to convert values greater than 1 to 0.

```
sign(rep(1, 4) %*% matrix(df$Value, 4))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    1    1    0
```

Note that this assumes that the vector is made up of 0s and 1s. It may fail if there are negative numbers.